# Use method to grab metadata and return as array

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have the below method that I want to retrieve some details from the database and return them inside my method:

Here is the `get_method` that I have:

```
public function get_authors()
    {

        // @todo: Return an array of profile objects
        // @todo: This should turn an array of profiles

        $profiles = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'author', true);
        var_dump($profiles);

        return $profiles;
}
```

Here is what `$profiles` var_dump's:
[image]

That is linked in my database as such 'author':
[image]

Inside my `wp_posts`, those two ID's are linked to posts - How would I go about extracting those posts inside my method?

[image]

Comment: So you basically want to return the posts made by those authors in "profiles"?

Comment: @EbrahimMohammed, correct, I'm outputting an foreach that just returns the names of those profiles - Each of those 'author' IDs is linked to a wp_post

Comment: Do you want it to be in the format of:

Array ( ['834'] => posts_array,['839'] => posts_array )

or something like that? where the key is the author id ?

Comment: I want to use the author IDs and just get the output of the posts particular to those IDs @EbrahimMohammed .. So let's say we have ID 834 from authors, that is a post inside `wp_posts` - I want to grab the two full posts into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function get_authors()
    {

        // @todo: Return an array of profile objects
        // @todo: This should turn an array of profiles

        $profiles = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'author', true);

        $final_array = array(); 

        foreach($profiles as $profile){
           $final_array[$profile] = get_posts([
              'author'    =>  $profile, 
              'orderby'       =>  'date',
              'order'         =>  'DESC' 
           ]);

        }
        return $final_array;
}
```

Here you go, this would simply loop over the author, and get the posts of each author.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ebrahim - I tried that method and when I var_dump $final_array, i'm getting empty array results.

Comment: Ah, empty results for both authors?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the graphic above - Give me 30 seconds.

Comment: Got it, give me a sec to debug something!

Comment: it is my pleasure man! and Wow, that's weird, it should work :O do you mind going to the database and to the posts table and query something like:

SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_author`='834'

But replace 'posts' with your posts table whatever it is!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207778/discussion-between-sle-and-ebrahim-mohammed).